# Python How to split text with no fixed blankspace

Tags: python, split

I have bellow text( get repsond from Zebra):

```
  30.0                DARKNESS          
  4 IPS               PRINT SPEED       
  +000                TEAR OFF          
  TEAR OFF            PRINT MODE        
  GAP/NOTCH           MEDIA TYPE        
  WEB                 SENSOR TYPE       
  MANUAL              SENSOR SELECT     
  THERMAL-TRANS.      PRINT METHOD      
  480                 PRINT WIDTH       
  0387                LABEL LENGTH      
  39.0IN   975MM      MAXIMUM LENGTH    
  CONNECTED           USB COMM.         
  BIDIRECTIONAL       PARALLEL COMM.    
  9600                BAUD              
  8 BITS              DATA BITS         
  NONE                PARITY            
  DTR & XON/XOFF      HOST HANDSHAKE    
  NONE                PROTOCOL          
  AUTO                SER COMM. MODE    
  <~>  7EH            CONTROL CHAR      
  <^>  5EH            COMMAND CHAR      
  <,>  2CH            DELIM. CHAR       
  ZPL II              ZPL MODE          
  NO MOTION           MEDIA POWER UP    
  FEED
```

I want to get values for each settings via python.
Expect to get something like a dict {'DARKNESS':30,'PRINT SPEED':'4 IPS' ....}
Normally, expect code is

```
for line in lines:
    x=line.split(' ')

the_value=x[0]
the_setting=x[1]
```

but it's without fixed blankspace. 
I don't have good idea to split it.
Using split() function isn't a good choose here.
The value also have blankspace as well.
I was stuck here.
Any idea?

Comment: Why are you stuck?

Comment: I don't know how to split it.

Comment: there is a split function in python

Comment: Have you tried splitting on a REGEX that includes more than one white space instead of just splitting on a single white space?

Comment: Are these `tab` delimited? You could use REGEX to split on the tab.

Comment: no, not ```tab``` here. I save it to file, and open with 16Hex editor, found it's 20 (blankspace) , so not tab.

Comment: So there's exactly 20 spaces between 30.0 and DARKNESS?

Comment: re.split(r'sorry how to write the filter here for no fixed blankspace?', line)

Comment: Does the second data column always commence at that position? If so, then it's easy to split each line: just use slicing.

Comment: You could do something along the lines of `re.split(r'\s{4,}', line)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using my suggestion in combination with yours, I got this to work (I made a txt file with your examples in it):

```
import re
file = open('untitled.txt','r')
my_dict = {}
for line in file:
    x,y = re.split(r'\s{4,}',line.strip())
    my_dict[y] = x
```

This is the output of the dictionary I made with this code:

> {'DARKNESS': '30.0', 'PRINT SPEED': '4 IPS', 'TEAR OFF': '+000', 'PRINT MODE': 'TEAR OFF', 'MEDIA TYPE': 'GAP/NOTCH', 'SENSOR TYPE': 'WEB', 'SENSOR SELECT': 'MANUAL', 'PRINT METHOD': 'THERMAL-TRANS.', 'PRINT WIDTH': '480', 'LABEL LENGTH': '0387', 'MAXIMUM LENGTH': '39.0IN   975MM', 'USB COMM.': 'CONNECTED', 'PARALLEL COMM.': 'BIDIRECTIONAL', 'BAUD': '9600', 'DATA BITS': '8 BITS', 'PARITY': 'NONE', 'HOST HANDSHAKE': 'DTR & XON/XOFF', 'PROTOCOL': 'NONE', 'SER COMM. MODE': 'AUTO', 'CONTROL CHAR': '<~>  7EH', 'COMMAND CHAR': '<^>  5EH', 'DELIM. CHAR': '<,>  2CH', 'ZPL MODE': 'ZPL II', 'MEDIA POWER UP': 'NO MOTION'}

Comment: It's better if you can remove the last line "FEED" and the "\x02" in first line(STX at the beginning）.

Comment: `line.rstrip().lstrip()` is the same as `line.strip()`, but slower.

Answer (score 0):

Use the python split function
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm

You can iterate over the lines using split('\n')
and then you can use regex to split the rest.

In your accepted answer it only splits when the whitespace between the key and value is 4 or bigger. This can give buggs when it is smaller. My solution normally fixes this.

```
dict = {}

for line in input.split('\n'):
    # Split the line in the correct parts
    myArray = re.findall('(^.{20})(.*)', line.lstrip().rstrip())

    # Check that you have found both key and value
    if len(myArray) > 0:
        myTupple = myArray[0]
        dict[myTupple[1].rstrip()] = myTupple[0].rstrip()
```

Comment: Thanks, but no, it's not single '\t' , it's not fixed blankspace.

Comment: @Niuya Are there always the same amount of characters in the first column, in other way, Does the second column always start on the same point?

Answer (score 0):

well, you can do the following

```
 file=open('yourfile','r').read().split('\n')
 lines=[line.split('     ') for line in file]
 items=[[i.replace(' ','') for i in item if i!=''] for item in lines]
 output_dict={i[0]:i[1] for i in items if i}
```

I used 3 main features of python here the one line loop

```
loop=[dosomething(item) for item in array if item=='somevalue'] #if statement is not necessary
```

,the **replace()** function

```
print 'Hello You'.replace('You','world') # outputs hello world
```

and the **split()** function

```
print 'hello,world'.split(',') # outputs ['hello',world]
```

you can find more documentation here: [python string methods](https://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/string-methods.html)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @TheDetective , you answer is useful.
Now better.
(comments have string limit，so I have to post in answer)

```
>>> for line in lines:
...     re.split(r'\s{4,}',line.rstrip().lstrip())
... 
['\x02  30.0', 'DARKNESS']
['4 IPS', 'PRINT SPEED']
['+000', 'TEAR OFF']
['TEAR OFF', 'PRINT MODE']
['GAP/NOTCH', 'MEDIA TYPE']
['WEB', 'SENSOR TYPE']
['MANUAL', 'SENSOR SELECT']
['THERMAL-TRANS.', 'PRINT METHOD']
['480', 'PRINT WIDTH']
['0387', 'LABEL LENGTH']
['39.0IN   975MM', 'MAXIMUM LENGTH']
['CONNECTED', 'USB COMM.']
['BIDIRECTIONAL', 'PARALLEL COMM.']
['9600', 'BAUD']
['8 BITS', 'DATA BITS']
['NONE', 'PARITY']
['DTR & XON/XOFF', 'HOST HANDSHAKE']
['NONE', 'PROTOCOL']
['AUTO', 'SER COMM. MODE']
['<~>  7EH', 'CONTROL CHAR']
['<^>  5EH', 'COMMAND CHAR']
['<,>  2CH', 'DELIM. CHAR']
['ZPL II', 'ZPL MODE']
['NO MOTION', 'MEDIA POWER UP']
['FEED']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I've already done it, you might as well have my answer too.

The two items of information occupy fixed places on each line. Therefore, string slicing can be used to pick them from lines. I omit the last line because there is no information about its field name.

```
>>> result = {}
>>> with open('temp.txt') as temp:
...     for line in temp.readlines():
...         if line.startswith('FEED'):
...             break
...         result[line[20:].strip()] = line[:20].strip()
...         
>>> result
{'DARKNESS': '30.0', 'PARITY': 'NONE', 'PRINT WIDTH': '480', 'DATA BITS': '8 BITS', 'PROTOCOL': 'NONE', 'COMMAND CHAR': '<^>  5EH', 'USB COMM.': 'CONNECTED', 'BAUD': '9600', 'PRINT MODE': 'TEAR OFF', 'MEDIA POWER UP': 'NO MOTION', 'DELIM. CHAR': '<,>  2CH', 'MAXIMUM LENGTH': '39.0IN   975MM', 'SENSOR SELECT': 'MANUAL', 'SENSOR TYPE': 'WEB', 'LABEL LENGTH': '0387', 'PARALLEL COMM.': 'BIDIRECTIONAL', 'CONTROL CHAR': '<~>  7EH', 'TEAR OFF': '+000', 'PRINT SPEED': '4 IPS', 'PRINT METHOD': 'THERMAL-TRANS.', 'HOST HANDSHAKE': 'DTR & XON/XOFF', 'ZPL MODE': 'ZPL II', 'MEDIA TYPE': 'GAP/NOTCH', 'SER COMM. MODE': 'AUTO'}
```